# How to save an array full of custom classes in iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsarray, saving-data

In an iOS application I am creating for a school project, I am having trouble saving data that is stored in an NSMutableArray. The array is created in the app delegate file, and then delegates for it are created in various other view controller files. The data stored in the array consists of custom classes made up of NSStrings and NSNumbers as properties.

I've read and followed many examples on this site for about a week now, but I can't for the life of me figure it out. I've also looked into core data, but I couldn't figure out how to implement that without completely starting over, and I'm pressed for time unfortunately.

Things I have tried:

**Archiving in the WillTerminate method. (activityArray is my array)**

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
NSString* documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* arrayFile = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"arrayFile"];
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:activityArray toFile:arrayFile];
[activityArray release];
```

**And then unarchiving in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method of the AppDelegate file**

```
    NSString* documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *arrayFile = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"arrayFile"];
if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:arrayFile]) {
    NSLog(@"yes");
    activityArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:arrayFile];
} else {
    activityArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

**As per suggestions on other questions, I did the following in the custom classes I have (this class has 2 NSStrings, activityName and activityDescription).**

```
- initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder {
self = [super init];
activityName = [[aCoder decodeObjectForKey:@"activityName"] retain];
activityDescription = [[aCoder decodeObjectForKey:@"activityDescription"] retain];
return self;
 }

-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder {
[aCoder encodeObject:activityName forKey:@"activityName"];
[aCoder encodeObject:activityDescription forKey:@"activityDescription"];
}
```

But none of this seems to work for me. Any help is gratefully appreciated. I feel like this should be a rather easy thing, but I just can't seem to get it.

Comment: What do you mean by "none of this seems to work"? Does the archiving not work? Or the unarchiving? Do you see the file being created? Your archiving method looks really weird. Why are you releasing activityArray? Why are you seemingly trying to archive it twice?

Comment: Oh wow, copy and paste error. Fixed the double archiving thing. And should it not be released when the application closes? As far as what doesn't work, when I close the application completely, and reopen it, all the data that used to be in the activityArray is not there. I'm not exactly sure if its a problem on the loading or saving side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Data is actually very simple and fast to implement. I made a [blog post](http://mikeahmarani.com/index.php?search=core+data) on quickly getting it setup a few months ago. Simply make entities to represent the different classes you have created or add the @dynamic properties yourself.

Keep in mind that Core Data behaves the same as an Array in that only objects can be stored. Thus you need to use NSNumber for int\floats, etc.

Comment: I think this is the route I'm going to follow, seeing as I might as well learn it now for the future. I'm gonna try this tonight.

Comment: I decided to rework parts of my code to work with core data, and it works like a charm! thank you, that blog post you linked to was fantastic.

Comment: Nice write up - but your link is bad.  Go to http://mikeahmarani.com/ and use 'find' for the text 'Core Data in 3 Simple Steps'

Answer (score 0):

You can save your array using the NSUserDefaults like this:

```
NSData *theData =  [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:activityArray];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:theData forKey:@"myArray"];
```

Then you can retrieve the save object as following:

```
NSData *theData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dataForKey:@"myArray"];
NSArray *activityArray = (NSArray *)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:theData];
```

However for this to work, you must implement the initWithCoder and encodeWithCoder methods for any custom objects involved as you have mentioned.

Comment: Where would you suggest placing these? The obvious for loading seemed to be didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, but a nslog test suggests that this method isnt invoked all the time, namely when starting the app from springboard.

Comment: Yes didFinishLaunchingWithOptions won't be invoked if the application supports multitasking and is being revived from background. For that purpose you have to use applicationWillEnterForeground and applicationDidEnterBackground delegate methods in conjunction with didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and applicationWillTerminate.

Answer (score 0):

Have you actually checked if your archiving code is executed at all? Under iOS 4 w/ multitasking enabled, `applicationWillTerminate:` is practically never called. You should consider putting the code in `applicationDidEnterBackground:` instead.

As for releasing the array after archiving, that would fail when the user leaves the app (it will be suspended) and later comes back (the app is just reactivated, not restarted). In that case, the fact that you released the array will cause your app to crash.

Comment: The way i was testing was closing the background process from the iphone home screen. I figure that calls didTerminate?

Comment: No, it doesn't. It just kills the process. And you could easily test this with the debugger.